# Android Webp presentation weired

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, webp

I use BitmapFactory to decode a Webp image and the result is weird in some devices.

The demo project is at https://github.com/peacepassion/allinonetry/tree/webp

The key code is very simple.

```
    InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
    }
```

The result of this demo behaves weird in Meizu MX4 Pro(OS 5.1.1) and behaved normal in Sony D6633(OS 4.4.4). And the picture looks normal in Chrome.

Meizu Weird Result
[image: Meizu Weird Result]

Sony Normal Result
[image: Sony Normal Result]

The image url is: http://fuss10.elemecdn.com/5/d8/691827c35ccd3c41d0f11faee4d54jpeg.jpeg?imageView2/0/w/200/h/200/format/webp

And I also post an issue to Android team, [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221750&thanks=221750&ts=1473128361), but there is no response yet.

Have you anyone have this problem before?

Comment: in `issue` url, you linked image instead posted issue